# Save URL of redirected page

Tags: html, http, session, url, redirect

I have "hotspot". Then i connect it - it redirects me to login page.
If i have few opened tabs and click on it during auth - they are redirected to my hotspot application.

How to save `url` except as a `GET` param?

Application is complex so hard to track all urls changes and pass `old url`. And it is not pretty.

Something like `window/tab` storage.

Maybe is there `window indentifier` that i can save in local-storage or web-sql?

Answer (score 0):

Window identificator can be saved in `window.name`. It saved across refreshes and urls changes.